# List of List - String Java 8 forEach feature. Looking for explanation of the output i got

Tags: java-8

I am trying to implement forEach function of Java 8. This programs prints lists of list content. (Please go through my code, my question is at the end of this post)
Below is my program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class OrderOfStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("a");
        list2.add("b");
        list1.add("c");
        list2.add("d");
        list1.add("e");
        list2.add("f");

        List<ArrayList<String>> list3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        list3.add((ArrayList<String>) list1);
        list3.add((ArrayList<String>) list2);


        list3.forEach(new Consumer<ArrayList<String>>(){

            @Override
            public void accept(ArrayList<String> t) {
                System.out.println( t.get(0));
                //System.out.println( t.get(1));


            }

        });


    }

}
```

Output of this program:

```
a
b
```

My question is : If i call list3.get(0) i should be getting a,c,e ? Isn't? Is this about Data Structure?

Comment: Aren't you asking for a print of position 0 "for each list" in list3?

Comment: You're not printing list3.get(0). You're calling get(0) on each element of list3 (i.e. on list1 and list2). Also, a consumer is intended to be used as a lambda: `list3.forEach(innerList -> System.out.println(innerList.get(0)))`

Comment: Arrangement of data in the memory according to me is something like this : list3->|list1|-> |a|c|e| 
                  |list2|->|b|d|f|
Now as you have described, innerList.get(0) should be |a| . Right ? How come "b" is being printed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote is the equivalent to the following in Java 7:

```
for (ArrayList<String> t : list3) {
    System.out.println(t.get(0));
}
```

Your contents of `list3` are as follows:

```
[a,c,e],[b,d,f]
```

For each of these two lists, you are printing the element at index `0`.  In the first sublist, that would be `a`; on the second, that would be `b`.